# Why this common eigenvectors do not depend on r?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics, spherical-coordinates, eigenfunctions

I have the two following operators:
$$
L_z=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi} \\
L^2=-\hbar^2 \left(\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
+\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}
\right)$$

As they commute (and are diagonalizable) we are looking for common eigenvectors $\psi_{m,l} $

$\psi_{m,l}$ being an eigenvector of $L_z$ yields to: $$L_z \psi_{m,l} = \hbar m\psi_{m,l} $$
$\psi_{m,l}$ being an eigenvector of $L^2$ yields to: $$L^2\psi_{m,l}=\hbar^2 \lambda \psi_{m,l} $$

where $\lambda$ is a positive eigenvalue (positive because $L^2$ can be written as ${L_x}^2 + {L_y} ^2 +{L_z}^2$) that can be written as $l(l+1)$ (because $f: l->l(l+1)$ establishes a bijection between $[0,+\infty[ $and $[0,+\infty[$)

My question is why the so-called eigenfunction $\psi_{m,l} (\theta, \phi)$ only depend on $\theta$ and $\phi$ and not on $r$?

In other words, why can't we write $\psi_{m,l} (r,\theta, \phi)$ ?

PS: $\hbar$ and $\hbar ^2$ are only there for dimensions (physical dimensions, like length, time..) purposes.

PS2: Both operators are diagonalizable because they are hermitian. Their hermiticity implies normality, and normality implies unitarily diagonalizable.

PS3: I have to say I don't know at all how to transpose those expressions of $L_z$, $L^2$ into matrices , maybe writting them as matrices would solve my question.. But I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Given the eigenfunctions $\psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi)$, because $L_z$ and $L^2$ have no radial dependency, you have the freedom to transform $$\psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi)\rightarrow \psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi,r)=f(r)\cdot \psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi)$$ for some function $f$, and $\psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi,r)$ will still be an eigenfunction of both operators. But we have the freedom to choose $f(r)=1$, which turns out to be the most convenient choice in situations where $L_z$ and $L^2$ appear (e.g. the eigenstates of hydrogen-like atoms).

Comment: Ok but why do you write $\psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi,r) = f(r)\psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi)$ Aren't we loosing generality ? I mean you can have $\psi_{m,l} $ depending on $r$,$\theta$ and $\phi$ without decomposing it into $f(r)\psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi)$ ?

Comment: When trying to obtain solutions for the eigenstates, one simply chooses the ansatz $\psi_{m,l}(\phi,theta)=\Phi(\phi)\Theta(theta)$, which yields the spherical harmonics [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics). Once you have these, the only possible $r-$dependence is the one where you have $\psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi,r)=f(r)\cdot \psi_{m,l}(\theta,\phi)$.